# Как найти все пути в графе между двумя вершинами, используя поиск в глубину в R

Tags: r, graph, dfs

Хотелось бы понять, как с помощью такого поиска в глубину найти ВСЕ пути в графе между заданными вершинами. Этот код находит 1 путь, а как потом вернуться, например, на шаг назад и попытаться поискать другие пути? На вход идет матрица смежности

```
f <- function(x,y,g,visit = c()){ 
 visit <- c(visit,x) 
 smez <- which(g[x,] != 0) 
 if(x == y){
   return(x)
 }else{
   path <- c()
   for(i in smez){
     if(sum(visit == i) == 0){
       path <- f(i,y,g,visit)
       if(length(path) > 0){
          path <- c(x, path)
          return(path)
       }
     }
   }
 }
  return(path)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода всех (простых) путей можно использовать чуть-чуть модифицированный поиск в глубину (или в ширину).

Отличие только в том, что пометки пройденных вершин должны быть не глобальными, а локальными для каждой ветви рекурсии.

Этого можно добиться, передавая новый экземпляр пометок (visit?) в рекурсивный вызов, либо работать с одним экземпляром, но очищать текущую пометку после рекурсивного вызова.