# Поиск всех маршрутов графа C#

Tags: c#, графы

Есть граф описанный матрицей

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

Необходимо из вершины v построить все маршруты до вершины x

Вот, что я написал

```
 private void dfs(int[][] a, ref bool[] visited, int n, int v, int x, ref int cnt, ref List<List<int>> p, ref List<int> r)
        {
            if (v == x)
            {
                cnt++;
                r.Add(x + 1);
                p.Add(r);
                r = new List<int>();
                return;
            }
            visited[v] = true;
            r.Add(v + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (a[v][i] == 1 && !visited[i])
                {
                    dfs(a, ref visited, n, i, x, ref cnt, ref p, ref r);
                }
            }
            visited[v] = false;
            r.Remove(v + 1);
        }
```

тут **a** - матрица графа, **visited** - массив посещенных вершин, **v** - начальная вершина, **x** - конечная вершина, **cnt** - количество маршрутов, **p** - список маршрутов, **r** - текущий маршрут

Но он некорректно работает, подскажите как это исправить.

Comment: `Необходимо из вершины v построить все маршруты до вершины x` - где в вашем коде маршруты?

Comment: `Но он некорректно работает, подскажите как это исправить.` исправить что?

Comment: как вы собираетесь строить "все" маршруты в графе с циклами?

Comment: Исправить построение маршрутов они некорректно строятся.

Comment: я не понимаю что такое "некорректно" и хз что делать с циклами.

Comment: Некорректно это вот так.

Comment: @Михаил `Некорректно это вот так.` Что именно вы хотели этим сказать???? Код в общем выглядит верно, может, какие детали я упускаю из-за особенностей шарпа. Что не так получается?

Comment: @tym32167 Простые пути ему нужно, без повторных заходов в одну и туже вершину.

Comment: Сейчас я получаю вот такой вот результат:
(1 3) ,
(4 3), 
(6 5 7 3),
(7 3)

А мне нужно найти все пути из вершины **v** в вершину **x**
Вы можете предложить своё видение данного метода для нахождения данных путей используя матрицу графа **a**

Comment: Моё видение [как раз такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138353/291659), как у вас реализовано, я только сомневаюсь в том, что вы делаете с r и p. [Вот рабочий пример на Delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925142/291659) с локальным хранением visited (Used). Попробуйте для отладки накапливать путь в строке, и выводить её при достижении x.  Как вы вызываете функцию, что получается путь с разным началом?

Comment: dfs(array, visited, n, 0, 2, ref cnt, ref p, ref r); вот таким образом вызываю

Comment: Выложите куда-нибудь полный код (без лишних деталей), чтобы его можно было воспроизвести

Comment: Спасибо, я воспроизвёл Ваш код, написанный на Delphi и он вроде корректно отработал.

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно постасить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот изменённый алгоритм, он отрабатывает корректно.
Спасибо за наводку MBo

```
private void findRoute(int[][] a, int v, int dest, int n, bool[] visited, string route)
    {
        if (v == dest)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += route + "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            visited[v] = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (a[v][i] == 1 && !visited[i])
                {
                    findRoute(a, i, dest, n, visited, route + (i+1) + " ");
                }
            }
            visited[v] = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю ещё код на Python, сделанный из вашего кода:

```
def dfs(a, visited, n, v, x, s):
    if (v == x):
        print(s + str(v))
        return
    visited[v] = True
    for i in range(n):
        if (a[v][i] == 1) and (not visited[i]):
            dfs(a, visited, n, i, x, s + str(v))
    visited[v] = False


n = 7
visited = [False]*n
a = [[0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,1,1,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,1,1,0]]

dfs(a, visited, n, 0, 2, "")
```

Вывод:

```
02
032
035462
03562
```

Comment: А разве в строке **print(s + str(v))**, **str(v)** - не лишний?

Comment: нет, ведь i-я вершина выше уровнем ещё не добавлена к строке пути (так и у вас было сделано). Можно модифицировать, делая рекурсивный вызов  `s + str(i)`, тогда  `print(s)` достаточно, если при первом вызове dfs исходную вершину положить в строку `dfs(a, visited, n, 0, 2, "0")` (если она вообще там нужна)

Comment: всё, увидел. Спасибо за разъяснение и за наводку)